# Creating a .NET object in IronRuby when a static .New() method is defined

Tags: constructor, ironruby

It seems impossible to create an object using its default constructor when there is a static .New() method defined on the class:

**.NET class:**

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void New()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Tester.New()");
    }

    public Tester()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In constructor");
    }
}
```

**IronRuby code:**

```
Tester.new
Tester.New
```

Both of these lines call **Tester.New()**, not the constuctor. It seems impossible to call the constructor of the **Tester** class.

Is there a workaround, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is just an unavoidable ambiguity. If you want to make CLI classes look like Ruby classes, you have no choice but to map the constructor to a `new` method. So, if you have both a *real* `new` method and a synthesized one which maps to a constructor, whatever you do, either the synthetic method shadows the real one or the other way around. Either way, you lose.

That's why all CLI classes have a synthetic `clr_new` method:

```
Tester.clr_new
# In constructor
```

Comment: It doesn't really do a translation in the second case. It does call the static New() method, as expected

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: Yes, of course. I don't know why I got confused there. If it *were* doing a translation it would obviously call the constructor.